# Cannot access phoenix webserver hosted in debian azure VM

Tags: azure, elixir, port, phoenix-framework, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to host a website in Azure using Phoenix. When I use a browser in the VM to go to the website it works and `nmap` is also showing that the ports are open.

However, when I go to the website from my own PC I cannot reach it. I suspected this to be caused by the network security group settings so I opened the ports:

[image]

However, it still doesn't work. What else can be causing this?

EDIT: nvm I must have been asleep when configuring the security group settings. Thanks to Justin Wood for pointing out the wrong port number.

Comment: You have the HTTPS (443) open. Do you also need to open the HTTP (80) port?

Comment: Oh that might very well be the thing iam missing here. Thanks for pointing that out. How did I miss this :P.

Comment: Since you solved it, you should post a proper answer to close this out (and not simply edit the question with the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have port 443 (HTTPS) open. You will probably want to open port 80 (HTTP) as well.